# How to access the data sent by arduino through bluetooth HC-05 chip in Visual Studio 2015 in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, arduino

I am trying to read the data sent by Bluetooth HC-05 Chip connected to arduino in my windows app(C# VS2015 app). I first tried to connect using the  SerialPort class. But there is no System.IO.Ports in visual studio 2015 ... i tried adding reference to System.dll also but it says that it is already present in references. Then I Found this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.aspx .... But i am unable to initialise the port say to COM5 ? should i use this class, or is there any better method?

Comment: can you elaborate why no `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class in VS 2015?

Comment: When i write Using System.IO.Ports , it gives an error as "The type or namespace 'Ports' does not exists in namespace 'System.IO' "

Comment: Are you sure the vs project is for Windows forms or Windows console app?

Comment: Also what is your .net framework version selected in the project and also have you put in the `using` directive.

Comment: @MiguelSanchez VS project is for universal windows platform(UWP) and the .NET framework version used is 4.5.2 .

Comment: have you checked up if `UWP` supports the `System.IO.Ports` namespace?

Comment: UWP doesn't support System.IO.Ports. That is OK. That's Why i was searching for an Alternative.

Comment: Can you move to Windows forms or console .. that support `System.IO.Ports` or are you stuck with `UWP`?